# How to view full error message in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, laravel-4

When laravel returns an error, the "message" property is truncated with an ellipses at the end. Many times I can't fully diagnose what's wrong because the message is not complete.

The image below shows an example error response from Laravel. The message is reporting that there is a syntax error in the query, but it's cut off so I don't know exactly where the syntax error is:
[image: Error response from Laravel]

Any idea of how to get Laravel to show the full message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to look it in your browser console, so it must be it truncating the message for you.

Take a look at your log file, it will show you the full message:

```
php artisan tail
```

Comment: For some reason the tail command wasn't being recognized by artisan, but your answer lead me to the `app/storage/logs/` and I found the log file with the error. Thanks!

Comment: Note for laravel 4.2, if your using logrotate this command will not work. Bcoz it is linked to /app/storage/logs/laravel.log